# Efficiently write LiDAR data to CSV with data.table::fwrite

Tags: r, csv, lidar, las, lidr

I have a LiDAR file (.las) that I ran through my R function:

```
writelas2csv <- function(x,y) {
  lasinspatpt <- list(as.spatial(readLAS(x)))
  write.csv(lasinspatpt, y, row.names = T)
}
```

but as we know write.csv is very slow, but

```
data.table::fwrite()
```

gives me an error that S4 isn't supported.

The available las to txt or las to CSV functions don't export all of the nonstandard fields I've added to the .las, and the function above does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```r
writelas2csv <- function(x,y) {
  data.table::fwrite(payload(x),y)
}
```

Comment: Since the goal of this is to write things efficently, another point to considder would be to **increase the number of threads that data.table uses** use the `nThread` argument in `fwrite()`. `fwrite()` can be paralelized well: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/fwrite.html

And here is how to set the environmental variables to change the number of used threatds in all data.table opperations: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/openmp-utils.html